# Prove that $f$ is constant

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be an entire function. if there exists $\delta> 0$ and $w\in \mathbb{C}$  such that

$$\left | f(z)-w \right | \geq \delta \qquad \forall z\in\mathbb C $$

Prove that $f$ is constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $g(z) = \frac{1}{f(z)-w}$, then $g$ is entire and $|g(z)| \le \delta$ for all $z$. What can you say about $g$ and hence $f$?

Comment: are entire and bounded?

Comment: Well, what can you say about a bounded entire function?

Comment: umm, I apply the Liouville theorem and according to that, then g is constant, then f is constant, right?

Comment: Well, first conclude that $g$ is constant, then the formula for $g$ shows that $f$ is constant.

Comment: ok yes, thank you very much for your help

Comment: @user99909: Glad to help.